# Does SMS parallel corpora in English exist publicly on internet?

Tags: sms, nlp, chat, smt, corpus

Does SMS parallel corpora in English exist publicly on internet?
I got NUS corpora of SMS but I need parallel corpora - one to one mapping of messages to correct English text.